# check availability of a room with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check if a certain room is available between a start and end date. I am doing this with a webservice function. This function gives back a list with all the reservations of a given room. If this list is empty, the room is available, else it's not. For know I have this query. But it always gives back all my reservations.

```
SELECT * FROM ARTICLES_RESERVERING res
INNER JOIN ARTICLES_ZAAL roo ON res.ZAALID = roo.ID 
WHERE roo.ID = @ZAALID
AND res.DATUM_BEGIN >= @DATUM_EINDE OR res.DATUM_EINDE <= @DATUM_BEGIN
```

Could anybody help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.

Change the last line to:

```
AND (res.DATUM_BEGIN >= @DATUM_EINDE OR res.DATUM_EINDE <= @DATUM_BEGIN)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * FROM ARTICLES_RESERVERING res
  INNER JOIN ARTICLES_ZAAL roo ON res.ZAALID = roo.ID 
  WHERE roo.ID = @ZAALID
  AND  @DATUM_EINDE between res.DATUM_BEGIN and res.DATUM_EINDE
```

I will rather use this query as using *OR* is generally expensive.

Comment: It was not part of the question to get it efficient; maybe that is a good thing to achieve, but your answer is just wrong.

Comment: @Argeman Well given query gives the desired result. That what was asked. There are diff ways to correct the query

Comment: Oh, now i see! Sorry, my fault, i have missed the point totally with my comment.